# Trouble creating Python loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a series of checkboxes with simple values (a, b, c, etc.) that when checked, would "trigger" a string of text to appear. The problem is that I will have a great number of checkboxes, and manually repeating my code below for each checkbox is going to be a mess. I am still learning Python and am struggling with creating a loop to make this happen.

Here is my current (working, but undesirable) code:

```
if a:
 a = 'foo'
if b:
 b = 'bar'
...
```

My attempt at the loop, which returns `box` as nothing:

```
boxes = [a, b, c, ...]

texta = 'foo'
textb = 'bar'
...

for box in boxes:
 if box:
  box = ('text=%s', box)
```

What should I do to get my loop functioning properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
mydict = {a:'foo', b:'bar', c:'spam', d:'eggs'}

boxes = [a, b, c]

for box in boxes:
   print('text=%s' % mydict[box])
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, you're just assigning to the local variable in the loop, not to the actual position in the list. Try this:

```
boxes = [a, b, c, ...]                   # boxes and texts have the same length
texts = ['texta', 'textb', 'textc', ...] # and the elements in both lists match

for i in range(len(boxes)):
    if boxes[i]:
        boxes[i] = texts[i]
```

Comment: or `for box, text in zip(boxes, texts):`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `zip()` and `enumerate()` here:

```
boxes = [a, b, c, ...]
texts = ['texta', 'textb', 'textc', ...]

for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(boxes,texts)):
    if x:
        boxes[i] = y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a,b,c = (1,0,11)
boxes = {a:'foo', b:'bar', c:'baz'}
for b in  ["text=%s" % boxes[b] for b in boxes if b]: 
    print b
```